# Notification when the value in Address Bar changes

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to get notified whenever the URL in the address bar (also known as location bar) changes. Using the following code, I tried to get notified when user navigates to another page (by clicking a link, using the back/forward button, by typing an address in the Location Bar, etc.) and also when user switches tabs.

```
var myExtension = {
oldURL: null,


init: function() {
    gBrowser.addProgressListener(this);
},

uninit: function() {
    gBrowser.removeProgressListener(this);
},

processNewURL: function(aURI) {
    if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL) return;

    // now we know the url is new...
    alert(aURI.spec);
    this.oldURL = aURI.spec;
},

// nsIWebProgressListener
QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI(["nsIWebProgressListener",
                                       "nsISupportsWeakReference"]),

onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
    this.processNewURL(aURI);
},

onStateChange: function() {},
onProgressChange: function() {},
onStatusChange: function() {},
onSecurityChange: function() {}
};


};


window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init() }, false);
window.addEventListener("unload", function() { myExtension.uninit() }, false);
```

but this code is getting reference error for XPCOMUtils and window.I m developing this code on firefox Add-on Builder. Is there anything i need to import???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i got the answer of my question but with click event i need it work on page load event
i tried document.addEventListener() but it didn't work

```
// This is an active module of the binitksingh (1) Add-on

    const contextMenu = require("context-menu"),
    data = require("self").data,
    notify = require("simple-notify").notify,
    tabs = require("tabs"),
    widgets = require("widget");


    exports.main = function(options, callbacks) {
   // Add a one-click option to addons bar.
    var widget = widgets.Widget({
    id: "Show-url",
    label: "Show URL",
    contentURL: "http://www.example.com/favicon.ico",


    onClick: function() {
        var tabworker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: data.url('js/find-url.js'),
            onMessage: processUrl
        });
        tabworker.port.emit('click');
    },
});


 }


  function processUrl(url) {
    if (url) {
        notify("Hello now u r on:\n" + url);
             } else {
                notify('ZOMG, error finding URL.');
                    }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at the beginning of the file to import XPCOMUtils.jsm

```
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm", this);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your content script, you can capture events for [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) and [pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event).

The hash change event is triggered when the URL changes in the site due to some type of navigation where you do not leave the page.

PageShow will fire when you navigate back of forwards.

Otherwise, if you are going to a page for the first time, it should be attaching your script for the first time. You can do a `*.port.emit` back to your main script.

Depending on if you are using PageMod or just attaching a worker on the tab may impact how you use these events, and this method requires using a content script which has access to the dom. Otherwise, you would have to periodically check the the tab's url property in main.js.